# drop down list in joomla for country selection on home page

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to add a drop down, listing all country names on a single page and make it my home page in joomla so when user goes to my site they choose their country and then the specific page loads for them.

I have not been able to find an extension that does this. Is there anything like this that I can use?

Comment: Instead of searching for a extension you can make a custom component or module , that would be very easy.According to the details you have provided , you just need a drop down containing the list of countries and once you click you will be redirecting to a common page if i am not wrong.Let me know if you still find hard in figuring out about dropdown

Comment: I just don't know how I would add that to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple module on having simple HTML dropdown.

Publish that module on a Menu Item and make that Menu Item as your HomePage.